# Is there a statistical method that can remove non-associated data points so as to improve correlation between 2 variables?

Tags: correlation, modeling, biostatistics

Lets say I have some data that can be described by 2 variables (features). Lets say I obtained a weak positive correlation between the 2 variables.  Is there any statistical method that can identify data points where the 2 variables are not associated and remove them so that the correlation between the 2 variables might improve?

Comment: What's your purpose for doing this? On the surface it seems as though this could be statistically dubious if you're simply trying to remove "bad" points. However I'd like to understand what you're attempting to do without jumping to any conclusions.

Comment: I also understand that this may be statistically dubious. I'm a biologist. In my case, there are certain genes in which the 2 features might not be correlated because of many other biological factors that induce noise whereas there are certain genes that might show a positive association between these 2 variables. I just want to identify genes(data points) where the positive trend or correlation (association) between the 2 variables exist and where they don't. In biology it is sometimes impossible to quantify all features, hence we depend on some features.

Comment: i) Why not throw out all but two data points. -> perfect correlation every time! You don't even need regression to fit the line joining them, just a pen and a ruler. Bliss! $\,$ ii) It sounds like you need a model for classifying points that relate to those "other biological factors" in some way. Which means you'd have to explain a good deal more about how this effect is supposed to operate with and without these "other factors". $\,$ iii) I can understand wanting to estimate correlation without being impacted by "noisy" points, but why do you need the correlation to be *higher* specifically?

Comment: Upvote to the 2nd assumption. This is what I want - classify noisy and non-noisy. But how do I do that?. For the iii) point, I was not aiming to "make" the correlation high but wanted a method to classify certain set of data points show a positive/negative association (trend) for the two features and certain points that show no association. Yes removal of noisy data points is what I want. Is there any method to quantify noise? How much more information do I need?

Comment: One way is to iteratively repeat finding the trend with each point removed, looking for the points whose removal gives the greatest improvement in the correlation. While this might be functional, in the end there would only be two points remaining - so you would need some sort of stopping criteria to prevent that from happening, although I can only think of subjective judgement on visual inspection after each iteration as such a criteria - and that's not so scientific.

Comment: Your initial reason, "...so that the correlation between the 2 variables might improve," is at odds with some of your reasons in the comments.